# SATA disk connected to mother board with SAS cable

Tags: sas, sata

I have a server mother board with SATA connections and 2U server case with 8X3,5" drive bays. The bays are connected with two SATA-> SAS cables (as show in the picture below)

So the connection is SATA on mother board -> SAS cable to hdd bay -> SATA harddrives. My problem is the BIOS cant find the drives. If I connect the drives directly to the mother board with an SATA cable, the bios finds them.

What is causing the drives to not be detected by the bios in this setup?

[image]

Comment: The SAS connectors are very likely connected to a seperate SAS controller which might not show the drives in BIOS. Check during POST if there is a SAS controller setup menu which can be launched.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but not the case.

Comment: You're not telling us what hardware you're using. Possibly, the SAS SFF-8087 connector is for an _optional_ SAS controller that isn't fitted. It's not very common to use a SAS/SATA fanout cable with a SATA controller.